# Rails Nested Form(DatePicker)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following Ryan Bates Episode#196 for Nested Forms.Add Fields does not support DatePicker. How to resolve thi?

Comment: check this if it helps: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#javascript-events

Comment: I am not using any gem for nested-forms. Can you provide me another solution.